# ESLint - "react/jsx-one-expression-per-line" error for rendering $

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslintrc

I want to render a dollar in jsx with eslint configured. But its not formatting the right way leaves me with this error -
`{row.revenue}` must be placed on a new line  ---> **react/jsx-one-expression-per-line**

example:

```
 const row = {
    revenue: 234,
  };
  return (
    <div>
      ${row.revenue}
    </div>
  );
```

I have tried this as well,

```
{ '$' }
{row.revenue}
```

but it's not working.

Can anyone help me with the right way to format without disabling the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put $${row.revenue} inside {``} (if i understood you correctly)